# angucomplete-alt cant access the selected.originalObject

Tags: angularjs

I create angucomplete inside repeat.
Could you please explain why my {{biaya.originalObject.id}} doesn't work?

Here the example: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Mx2EvmwDEhnGtR7ox3CO?p=preview)

```
<tr ng-repeat="biaya in data_biaya | filter:{tahapan_id : x.id}" ng-init="biaya.editing=[]">
    <td>
       {{$index+1}}
    </td>
    <td ng-click="biaya.editing[2]=true" ng-init="biaya.editing[2]=false;" >
        <span ng-if="!biaya.editing[2]">{{biaya.uraian}}</span>
        <angucomplete-alt ng-if="biaya.editing[2]"
             id="ex1"
             focus-in="focusIn()"
             focus-out="focusOut()"
             placeholder="Cari jenis biaya"
             pause="100"
             selected-object="biaya"
             local-data="jenis_biaya"
             search-fields="nama"
             title-field="nama"
             minlength="1"
             initial-value="{{biaya.uraian}}"
             input-class="form-control form-control-small">
       </angucomplete-alt>
     </td>
     <td>
        SelectedId = {{biaya.originalObject.id}}
     </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: SelectedId = {{biaya.originalObject.id}} , what its should show?

Comment: angucomplete show after i clicked the second column and it should show selected $scope.jenis_biaya based on user pick/select

Comment: I found the problem, angucomplete doesnt work with ng-if
<angucomplete-alt ng-if="biaya.editing[2]"